# Como recuperar valor de variável (custom property) CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Por exemplo, tenho uma variável definida na minha folha de estilos:

```
:root {
  --limite: 90vw;
}
```

Como recuperar o valor dessa variável CSS no jQuery de forma tal que a cada vez que essa resolução alterar (sim, ela mudará ao alterar a resolução do navegador), o jQuery captar essa alteração junto?

Comment: *"variável CSS?"* variável o a propriedade? quer ler o valor de `--limite`  é isso?

Comment: isso mesmo, variavel CSS, não propriedade!

Answer (score 1):

Não tem porque utilizar jQuery para isso! :-) Você pode utilizar o método [`getPropertyValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/getPropertyValue), disponível no protótipo de objetos do tipo [`CSSStyleDeclaration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration).

Um exemplo simples:

```js
// Equivalente ao pseudo-seletor `:root` no CSS.
const root = document.documentElement;

// Define uma "variável" na raiz:
root.style.setProperty('--my-var', 'rgb(255, 0, 0)');

// Obtém a "variável":
const result = root.style.getPropertyValue('--my-var');
console.log(result); //=> rgb(255, 0, 0)
```

O problema é que utilizar `getPropertyValue` na `CSSStyleDeclaration` retornada pela propriedade `style` de qualquer elemento não funcionará para obter as "variávies" definidas pelo CSS, uma vez que a propriedade `style` recupera somente os estilos definidos *inline* no próprio elemento.

Para obter "variáveis" CSS definidas na folha de estilos, você deve utilizar a `CSSStyleDeclaration` retornada pelo método [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) mediante aplicação com o próprio elemento.

Um exemplo:

```js
// Obtém a raiz:
const root = document.documentElement;

// Obtém os estilos computados para a raiz:
const computedStyles = window.getComputedStyle(root);

// Obtém a "variável":
const result = computedStyles.getPropertyValue('--my-var');
console.log(result); //=> rgb(255, 0, 0)
```

```css
:root {
  --my-var: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

Como estilos computados herdam regras CSS definidas em qualquer elemento parente, você pode utilizar esse artifício em qualquer elemento descendente do elemento raiz.

No entanto, para facilitar a computação dos estilos, prefira sempre buscar pelo elemento mais próximo àquele que definiu a regra. Neste caso, o próprio `:root`.

---

Em relação ao "observar alterações" automaticamente, não há forma definida para se fazer isso. Uma opção é encapsular a lógica que mostrei acima em uma função e chamá-la sempre que o usuário alterar a resolução.

Você pode fazer esse tipo de invocação mediante emissão do evento [`resize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize), por exemplo.

---

> Esta resposta foi baseada [nesta pergunta (e respostas)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36088655/7445826) do SOen.

Comment: Acho que entendi. Mas acho que isso não vai funcionar. Não o teu código, mas a minha ideia de solução. Veja: https://codepen.io/carcleo/pen/yLVOxMv, estou criando um Slider. Tudo funciona bem. No entanto, quando vou reduzindo e ampliando o tamanho da janela, o javascript não acomapan0a  o tamanho da div.containner e então dá um containner maior que as imagens.

Comment: Eu adicionei uma observação sobre isso no final da resposta (editei agora há pouco), você chegou a ler? Não há como "observar" diretamente o valor da _custom property_ definida na folha de estilos. O que você pode fazer é recomputá-la (e, portanto, lê-la novamente) mediante a emissão de algum evento, como o `resize`.

Comment: Entendi. Vou tentar aqui, obrigado. Mas , se não for pedir muito, pode, por favor, ler meu comentário?

Comment: Ué, moço, eu li seu comentário, tanto é que o respondi! :P Está falando de qual comentário? :)

Comment: https://codepen.io/carcleo/pen/yLVOxMv